# Unable to read the String from json data in android via url

Tags: android, json

I started programming android and came across a problem with json.
I was trying to get the data as a string from the json, `{"results":{"results_start":1,"results_returned":4,"api_version":"2.00","results_available":4,"school":[{"name_kana":"Cook","kyoten":{"name_kana":"CookTime","kyoten_type_cd":"TK","shiryo_url":{"qr":"http://webservice.recruit.co.jp/common/qr?url=https"}]}`.

I tried to use the code below to get the value from "name_kana" from the json data above with the following code but cannot get the string.

```
 String name_kana="";
            try{
                JSONObject reader= new JSONObject(requestresult);
                JSONArray school = reader.getJSONArray("school");
                for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
                    reader = school.getJSONObject(i);
                }
                name_kana = reader.optString("name_kana");
            }catch(JSONException ex){

            }
        t = (TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.test);
        t.setText(name_kana);
```

Since I'm new to android, would you mind if you can explain or provide me with the hints so that I can get the string data from the json mentioned above ? I would love to hear from you !

Comment: Are you trying to read the json as plain String as it is ?

Comment: your json has parsing error.

Comment: That isn't valid json, is that the entire json in string form? You should catch and post your exception, it will likely give you more clarification.

Comment: @user3264924 If your editor does not help you validate your json. You can paste your JSON in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and see where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not parsing because it is not a valid json. Try using [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for validating your json.

The valid json seems to be this

```
    {
    "results": {
        "results_start": 1,
        "results_returned": 4,
        "api_version": "2.00",
        "results_available": 4,
        "school": [{
            "name_kana": "Cook",
            "kyoten": {
                "name_kana": "CookTime",
                "kyoten_type_cd": "TK",
                "shiryo_url": {
                    "qr": "http://webservice.recruit.co.jp/common/qr?url=https"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I found the solution!